# Trouble setting ADC to fully respond

Tags: css, c, mplab, adc

I have made a simple program that controls a 10-LED bar graph and the speed in which the LEDs change is supposed to be controlled by a 10K POT. I am using 16F88 (and CSS Compiler/Mplab v8.91) for this simple Program, but the 10k POT is not responding to a full turn of the POT.  Only toward in the Last 5% of MAX on the POT, does the speed change a few steps. From Minimum to 95% (of MAX) there is no change in the speed of output of the LEDs.

All other parts of the code with. Just need to get this POT figured out.

Thanks in Advance!

```
#include <16f88.h>
#device ADC=10
#device *=16
#ZERO_RAM

//////// Fuses: LP,XT,HS,EC_IO,NOWDT,WDT,NOPUT,PUT,MCLR,NOMCLR,BROWNOUT
//////// Fuses: NOBROWNOUT,LVP,NOLVP,CPD,NOCPD,WRT,NOWRT,DEBUG,NODEBUG,CCPB0
//////// Fuses: CCPB3,PROTECT,NOPROTECT,INTRC,INTRC_IO,RC,RC_IO,FCMEN
//////// Fuses: NOFCMEN,IESO,NOIESO
#fuses INTRC_IO,NOWDT,PUT, NOMCLR, PROTECT, NOBROWNOUT, NOLVP, NOWRT, NOCPD
#use delay(clock=4000000)
#use fast_io(A)
#use fast_io(B)

#byte PORTA = 0x5
#byte PORTB = 0x6
/**********************************************************************/
/* PIC interface                                                      */
/**********************************************************************/
#bit LED1           = PORTA.1           //Output
#bit LED2           = PORTA.2
#bit LED3           = PORTA.3
#bit LED4           = PORTA.4
#bit LED5           = PORTA.6       
#bit LED6           = PORTA.7
#bit LED7           = PORTB.0
#bit LED8           = PORTB.1
#bit LED9           = PORTB.2
#bit LED10          = PORTB.3


#bit LED_GREEN        = PORTB.4
#bit SP_OUT           = PORTB.5         //Short Pulse
/**************************************************************************
* Global Variables
**************************************************************************/
int speed, state, adc0;
unsigned int16 t,t1, t2,t3, t4;
short flag, flag1,flag2;

/**************************************************************************
* Speed
**************************************************************************/              
void f_speed(void) {
    SET_ADC_CHANNEL(0);
    delay_us(100);
    adc0 = READ_ADC(); 
    
    if(adc0<1) adc0=1;

    if(adc0>0 && adc0<=32)
          t2=2800;                  //280ms
    if(adc0>32 && adc0<=64)
          t2=2450;;                 //245ms
    if(adc0>64 && adc0<=96)
          t2=2100;                  //210ms
    if(adc0>96 && adc0<=128)
         t2=1750;  
    if(adc0>128 && adc0<=160)
          t2=1400;
    if(adc0>160 && adc0<=192)
         t2=1050;
    if(adc0>192 && adc0<=224)
          t2=700; 
    if(adc0>224 && adc0<=256)
          t2=350;                  //35ms

}

/**************************************************************************
* Mode 1  basic Scan 
**************************************************************************/              
void f_mode_1(void) {
   
      // SPM_BASIC_SCAN
         if(flag1){
            flag1=0;
            flag2=1;
            t=0;
         } 
         if(flag2){
             if(t>10){    
                 SP_OUT=1;
                 flag2=0;
                 t4=0;
             }
          }     
          switch(state){
            case 1:
//              PORTA = 0b00000001;            // SCAN STARTS
                LED1=1;     
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=2;
                   LED1=0;
                }
                break;
                
            case 2:  
                LED2=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=3;
                   LED2=0;
                }
                break; 

             case 3:  
                LED3=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=4;
                   LED3=0;
                }
                break;
 
              case 4:  
                LED4=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=5;
                   LED4=0;
                }
                break;
 
               case 5:  
                LED5=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=6;
                   LED5=0;
                }
                break;
 
             case 6:  
                LED6=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=7;
                   LED6=0;
                }
                break; 

              case 7:  
                LED7=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=8;
                   LED7=0;
                }
                break; 

              case 8:  
                LED8=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=9;
                   LED8=0;
                }
                break; 

             case 9:  
                LED9=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=10;
                   LED9=0;
                }
                break;
 
              case 10:  
                LED10=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=11;
                   LED10=0;
                }
                break; 
              case 11:  
                LED9=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=12;
                   LED9=0;
                }
                break;
            case 12:  
                LED8=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=13;
                   LED8=0;
                }
                break; 

             case 13:  
                LED7=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=14;
                   LED7=0;
                }
                break;
 
              case 14:  
                LED6=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=15;
                   LED6=0;
                }
                break;
           case 15:  
                LED5=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=16;
                   LED5=0;
                }
                break;
            case 16:  
                LED4=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=17;
                   LED4=0;
                }
                break; 

             case 17:  
                LED3=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=18;
                   LED3=0;
                }
                break;
 
              case 18:  
                LED2=1;
                if(t3>t2){
                   t3=0;
                   state=1;
                   LED2=0;
                }
                break;

        }
}

/**************************************************************************
* Clear_LED
**************************************************************************/
void Clear_LED(void){
   LED1=0;
   LED2=0;
   LED3=0;
   LED4=0;
   LED5=0;
   LED6=0;
   LED7=0;
   LED8=0;
   LED9=0;
   LED10=0;
}
/*************************************************************************
* timer0 Interrupts  100useg
**************************************************************************/
#INT_TIMER0
void TIMER0_isr()
{
    set_timer0(156);
    t3++;        // Speed timer 
    t4++;        //Short pulse timer
    if(t4>5000) {
        t4=0;    //500ms 
        SP_OUT = 0;
    }       
}

/*************************************************************************
* timer1 Interrupts 100ms
**************************************************************************/
#INT_TIMER1
void TIMER1_isr()
{
 set_timer1(53036);
    t++;
    t1++;    
}

/**************************************************************************
* interruption for change RB4-RB7
**************************************************************************/
#int_rb               
void detect_rb_change(void) {
   disable_interrupts(INT_RB); 
   int current;
   static int last=0;
   current=PORTB;
          
    if ((!bit_test(current,7))&&(bit_test(last,7))) {
         flag=!flag;
         if(flag){  //ON
            LED_GREEN=1;
            state=1;
            t3=0;
            f_speed();
            flag1=1;
         } else{  //OFF
            LED_GREEN=0;
         } 

    }   
    last=current;
    enable_interrupts(INT_RB); 
}

/**************************************************************************
* Main Progran
**************************************************************************/
void main()
{  
   set_tris_a(0x00);
   set_tris_b(0x80); 
   setup_adc_ports(sAN0); 
   setup_adc(VSS_VDD | ADC_CLOCK_DIV_8);
   setup_timer_1(T1_INTERNAL|T1_DIV_BY_8);
   setup_timer_0(T0_INTERNAL|T0_DIV_0);
   
   Clear_LED();
   LED_GREEN=0;
   SP_OUT=0;
   flag=false;
   state=1;
   f_speed();
   t3=0;
   t1=0;
   set_timer1(53036);   //Interrupts 100ms
   set_timer0(156);     //Interrupts 100us
   enable_interrupts(INT_TIMER0);
   enable_interrupts(INT_RB);
   enable_interrupts(INT_TIMER1);
   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL); 

   while(1)
   {
   if(flag){       //ON
     if(t1>10){
           t1=0;
           f_speed();
     }
      f_mode_1(); 

    } else{
      Clear_LED();
     
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please look up the range of values returned by `READ_ADC()`. Are you sure that it is [0 .. 256]? It might be [0 .. 1023] or [0 .. 2047] (note the last value is one smaller than a power of two) or even [-1024 .. +1023].